# MySql - Change return value if value exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I m using the `selectSellerID` function to retrieve a user's id.

```
public function selectSellerID($item_id)
{
    if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM items WHERE id = ?"))
    {
        $q->bind_param("i", $item_id);
        $q->execute();
        $q->bind_result($id);
        $q->fetch();
        $q->close();

        return $id;
    }
        return false;
}
```

The item_id can also appear in another table which is the resell table. In this case the user_id will change. Below is the resell table.

```
+----+---------+---------+-------+------+
| id | user_id | item_id | price | date |
+----+---------+---------+-------+------+
|  2 |      18 |      27 |    91 | NULL |
|  3 |       1 |      27 |    90 | NULL |
|  4 |       1 |      27 |    75 | NULL |
+----+---------+---------+-------+------+
```

So I need to change the function to check if the item_id is presend in the resell table, then only grab the latest user_id, as it may be resold multiple times. What is the best way to change the function other than doing a second query?

Comment: So as per the sample resell table, will the latest user id be 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL `JOINS`.

Joining `items` table with `resell` table and then ordering the result set with highest `id` will give the desired results.

Try below query:

```
SELECT IF(r.user_id IS NULL, i.user_id, r.user_id) AS user_id
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN resell r
ON i.id = r.item_id
WHERE i.id = ?
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes but what if there is no entry in the `resell` table? The original item is added in the `items` table. Then it will be included in the `resell` table optionally ... it won't always be there. So the query should check if `item_id` exists in the `resell` table, then get the latest `user_id`. The way you have it now won't get me the user_id from `items` table. Correct?

Comment: I guess it should be a LEFT JOIN and selecting the user_id fields from both tables. If the r.user_id is NULL then there is no reseller and you'd use the i.user_id.

Comment: Ohh! In that case we can use LEFT JOIN as suggested by @VolkerK. Will update my post.

Comment: Nice ... it works. That mysql if is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
$q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT rsl.user_id FROM items itms LEFT JOIN resell rsl ON itms.id = rsl.item_id WHERE itms.id = ? ORDER BY rsl.id DESC LIMIT 1");
```